# Confusion with Summations

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am having a little bit of confusion regarding summations.

I know that $$\sum_{i=m}^n a_i = a_{m}+a_{m+1}+\cdots +a_{n-1}+a_n$$

Here is my confusion. How do we interpret/decompose the following:

$$ \sum_{i=m}^n a_i~~~~,~~~m=0,1,2,3,,,,k~~?  $$

Comment: $\sum\limits_{i=m}^m a_i = a_m$.

Comment: It's just $a_m$, one term.  Why is that confusing to you?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. I meant n, not m.

Comment: @Josh: The last statement I interpret as $m$ may be an integer $0\le m \le k$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it the $m=0,1,2,3,\dots,k$ that's confusing you?  That just means there are several sums: $$
\text{$\sum_{i=0}^na_i$, $\ \ \sum_{i=1}^na_i$, $\ \ \sum_{i=2}^na_i$, $\ \ \dots\ $, $\ \sum_{i=k}^na_i$}$$

Comment: Yes. So in this case, we don't get a unique sum?

Comment: That's right, the $m$ indexes $k+1$ different sums.  They could turn out to be equal if the $a_n$'s are special (e.g. if all of them are zero).  But usually they'll all be different.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Is there reason why such a sum would be required at all. I was wondering if you could give an application of when one would want to use that notation.

Comment: Oh yes they come up everywhere.  For example suppose you want to expand $(a+b)^n$ for $n=1,2,\dots,k$.  You can write it as $\sum_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}a^ib^{n-i}$, $n=1,2,\dots,k$.

Comment: i wanted an example where the lower index changes. ;)